# Is scribe service immutable?

Tags: java, scribe

I'm just wondering whether the service created from service builder is immutable and therefore safe to be instantiated once and be used multiple times to serve multiple oauth authentications for user signups in my webapp ?

Comment: Yes, see readme.md at GitHub: Threadsafe

Hit Scribe as hard and with many threads as you like.

Comment: @LeosLiterak: Thanks ! If you would put that as the answer, i will gladly set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Btw take a look at scribe clone https://github.com/hhru/subscribe

Comment: @LeosLiterak: Nice substitute. I'm currently using subscribe for the google 2.0 api. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scribe library is immutable, see [README.md](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/README.md#threadsafe):

> **Threadsafe**
>
> Hit Scribe as hard and with many threads as you like.